# using mobile device setting how to switch environment

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, environment-variables, settings

Earlier I have set environment variable using schema for selecting build for dev/test/stage/production.

Now once I run application in dev environment my build is target to development environment,

Using mobile device setting how to switch different environment.

Is device setting allow App to switch different environment variables?

**Something like Change your API Baseurl from iPhone device Settings**

Comment: No, you cant change settings with iPhone device settings.

Comment: @msusare concept called settings build, you can add new file settings.build to YourProject.xcodeproj

Comment: Based on schema target how configure settings.build ?